# Does Koa safely handle errors?

Tags: node.js, koa

The [Nodejs API](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html#domain_warning_don_t_ignore_errors) states...

> By the very nature of how throw works in JavaScript, there is almost
>   never any way to safely "pick up where you left off", without leaking
>   references, or creating some other sort of undefined brittle state.

However Koa traps errors and avoids exiting the nodejs process. What enables Koa to safely flout this advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are primarily two cases where koa can not safely handle errors.

Thrown errors on different ticks:

```
app.use(function* () {
  setImmediate(function () {
    throw new Error('boom')
  })
})
```

Emitter errors that are not set as `response.body=`:

```
app.use(function* () {
  this.response.body = stream.pipe(zlib.createGzip())
})
```

Any function or library that does the first case is malformed and should not be used. If the function/library uses promises and/or callbacks correctly, it will never happen.

For emitters, simply always set each stream as the body (or use middleware):

```
 app.use(function* () {
  this.response.body = stream
  this.response.body = this.response.body.pipe(zlib.createGzip())
})
```

Koa does this by allowing you to use try/catch on "async" stuff, specifically callbacks and promises. You can't, however, try/catch an error thrown on a different tick or an emitter.